# A complex integral using Cauchy's Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, compute $\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{e^z}{z^m}dz$.

This exercise is supposed to be solve using Cauchy's Formula. The case when $m\leq 0$ could be solved by setting the auxiliar function $f(z)=e^z z^{-m+1}$ and the integral becomes $\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{f(z)}{z-0}dz$, but if $m>0$ $f(z)$ is not holomorphic in $z=0$.

Comment: $\oint_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^m}dz=2\pi  i((m-1)!)^{-1}f^{(m-1)}(z_0)$. Take $f(z)=e^{z}$. Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula

Comment: Is there any other tool, perhaps other than Cauchy's formula for the moment, you might be able to utilize to solve the problem for the case when $m\gt 0$?

Comment: Liouville, Picard's Little Theorem, Schwarz reflexion principle, Cauchy Goursat, Green for rectangles and some corollaries. This are the intended content of the guide.

Comment: The formula I stated is also called Cauchy's Integral Formula; just more general than the one you are trying to use. The value of your integral is $2\pi i((m-1)!$ and it is  immediate from this formula. Is your question answered now? (You can also evaluate it by expanding $e^{z}$ in a power series and integrating term by term)

Comment: If m>0 I can apply the general formula of the m-th derivative plugging f(z)=e^z, and m<=0 is solved as I wrote before, am I right?
Thank you for the idea, I knew the formula but I didn't realise to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $m \in \Bbb{Z}$ be such that $m \geq 1$. As the any derivative of $e^z$ is just $e^z$, one has, by Cauchy's integral formula

$$\int_{\vert z \vert = 1}\frac{e^z}{z^m}dz=\frac{2\pi i}{(m-1)!} \bigg(\frac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}} e^z \bigg\vert_{z=0}\bigg)=\frac{2\pi i}{(m-1)!} (e^0)=\frac{2\pi i}{(m-1)!}.$$

If $m \leq -1$ the answer is zero as the function is analytic everywhere by Cauchys Theorem. You tell me, what happens if its $m=0$.